# What did the prophet say about whom the first caliph should be?

Tags: hadith, prophet-muhammad, ali, khilafah, caliph

As I know, there is an ongoing discussion on who the first caliph should have been, but what did the holy prophet Muhammed s.a.s. said about this matter? What was his commandment? Is there a safe source for this information?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Muslims divided into two teams because of this:

**The first team**

A.k.a *Shia* are who believe that the Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) selected *Ali ibn Abi Talib* as a caliph after him in various situations, the most famous one is *Hadith Al-Ghadeer*:

> O people, Allah the Most Kind the Omniscient has told me that no apostle lives to more than half the age of him who had preceded him. I think I am about to be called (to die) and thus I must respond. I am responsible and you are responsible, then what do you say?' They said, 'We witness that you have informed, advised and striven. May Allah bless you.' He said, 'Do you not bear witness thatthere is no god but Allah and that Muhammad is His servant and Apostle, and that His Heaven is true, His Hell is true, death is true, the Resurrection after death is true, that there is no doubt that theDay of Judgment will come, and that Allah will resurrect the dead from their graves?' They said, 'Yes, we bear witness'. He said, 'O Allah, bear witness.' Then he said, '**O people, Allah is my Lord and I am the lord of the believers. I am worthier of believers than themselves. Of whomsoever I had been Master (Mawla), Ali here is to be his Master. O Allah, be a supporter of whoever supports him (Ali) and an enemy of whoever opposes him and divert the Haq to Ali**. [This is a full research about the Hadith+ Sources](http://www.schiiten.com/backup/AhlelBayt.com/www.ahlelbayt.com/articles/rebuttals/ghadir-khumm.html)

**The second team**

A.k.a *Sunni* are who believe that the prophet (PBUH) didn't choose a caliph after him and the Muslims were free to choose whom they saw best as caliph by *Shura*, for more information, see [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Succession_to_Muhammad#The_Sunni_view_of_the_succession)

Comment: Down vote, as answer is not based on what questionnaire is asking. he is asking that IF Prophet Muhammad chose a khalifa, or not, and NOT about the point that what happened after it. Please try to be precise in answering , to specifically what questionnaire has asked.

Comment: @Farhan it's a one and a half line to add more value to the answer, I don't believe an answer like "Sunni are who believe he didn't" would be a satisfying answer.

Comment: @Farhan You should read what [Shog9](http://stackexchange.com/users/620) has to say about voting [here](http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/questions/790).

Comment: This answer needs improvement. Trying adding the details you found on those articles in an objective manner and then mention were you got them from, instead of asking the reader to go and read for themselves.

Comment: @Bleeding Fingers Should I add what happened after that? As Farhan said, the asker didn't ask for it. That's why I didn't write it directly to the answer, instead inserted a link so that anyone who want to further research can. + I think that hadith Al-Ghadeer is enough as an answer, the link is only for further research

Comment: You could elaborate on "hadith Al-Ghadeer" and "shura". Some relevant quotes and description on both "teams". Are those teams exhaustive? Write and answer in a manner that the reader's cursor lounges to the upper triangle and wishes there were more (s)he could award you with.

Comment: What you said about Sunni View is mostly false, those who really said any muslim could be a caliph are the khwarij (kharijite) and Abadi people. Sunni said that the indications of our Messenger (peace be upon him) were favorable for abu Bakr, as for example he lead the prayers during the Messengers sickness. Some even say that the caliph could only be from Quraish, which one could apparently find in some ahadith (but i guess they are weak or fabricated), personally i tend to the kharijite opinion, as this is most likely to go ahead with islmic thinking!